# List of Drones with MAVLink support

Tags: drones

I am starting to learn how Drone communication works and I think it would be best to buy one where I can use the Dronekit library. I've been searching the internet for drones that are compatible with the MAVLink protocol but the description on the product pages isn't quite clear on this. Does anyone have a list of MAVLink compatible drones?

Comment: your question is not related to IoT, so it is off topic here ... that said, the specific answer to your question is `yes`

Comment: Oh ok, on what board should I post this instead? Can I have the list?

Comment: i do not know where you could ask

Comment: There's a board "Drones and model aircraft"